# Multiple Dictionary Time Complexity Architecture

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone would be willing to help me determine the most efficient time complexity method for the following objective:

I would like to print a comprehensive and non redundant list of results from 3 dictionaries. I would also like the entries that match between the dictionaries to merge on a single line and to fill those entries with "NA" if they don't. So far my method is as follows:

```
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2 and key in dict3:
        output.write(str(dict1[key][0]) + "\t" + str(dict2[key][0]) + "\t" + str(dict3[key][0]))
    elif key not in dict2 and key in dict3:
        output.write(str(dict1[key][0]) + "\t" + "NA" + "\t" + str(dict3[key][0]))
    elif key in dict2 and key not in dict3:
        output.write(str(dict1[key][0]) + "\t" + str(dict2[key][0]) + "\t" + "NA")
    else:
        output.write(str(dict1[key][0]) + "\t" + "NA" + "\t" + "NA")
for key in dict2:    
    if key not in dict1 and key in dict3:
        output.write("NA" + "\t" + str(dict2[key][0]) + "\t" + str(dict3[key][0]))
    elif key not in dict1 and key not in dict3:
        output.write("NA" + "\t" + str(dict2[key][0]) + "\t" + "NA")   
for key in dict3:
    if key not in dict2 and key not in dict3:
        output.write("NA" + "\t" + "NA" + "\t" + str(dict3[key][0]))
```

I feel like there is a much more efficient way (in terms of time complexity) to structure this. I am working with large files and any help would be appreciated in assisting me to speed up my code. I am new to computer science, so if it would be at all possible, I would like to avoid using additional packages (however these tips are still appreciated!) and focus on basic architecture to ensure I have strong fundamental skills in place as I move forward.

Comment: Why not loop over `set(dict1.keys()) | set(dict2.keys()) | set(dict3.keys())` and test if each element in the union is in every single key set. Optimal complexity? Do not know .... but very readable.

Comment: Complexity is definitely a high priority in this case. Thank you very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Complexity wise there is not much you can improve here. You're eliminating possibilities one by one and this is really as fast as you can go.

One could do the membership check only once for each key and dictionary, but membership checks in dictionaries are O(1) so I doubt it will impact your performance.

Python does have the pandas module though, which will do what you need in just one line:

### Script:

```
first=dict(a=1,b=3,c=5)
second=dict(d=1,b=5,f=5)
third=dict(f=1,q=3,a=5)
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(first=first,second=second,third=third),)
print(df)
```

### Output:

```
   first  second  third
a    1.0     NaN    5.0
b    3.0     5.0    NaN
c    5.0     NaN    NaN
d    NaN     1.0    NaN
f    NaN     5.0    1.0
q    NaN     NaN    3.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how you would implement pandas to print neatly formatted columns for a dictionary containing lists of lists as values? I could work with entire values or even better yet specific fields from the inner and outer lists.